# Using crypto.subtle.deriveKey HKDF and ECDSA/elliptic curve as the base?

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I want to use a none-exportable EC private key as the base key for crypto.subtle.deriveKey with HKDF but it doesn't seem that this is possible.

Is there a way that subtle crypto can meet my requirements?

1. The key must be available for ECDSA
2. The key must be available as the base key for HKDF

I wondered if storing the key as if it were another algorithm might work?

Comment: If you can use the key for DH then you could perform key agreement with a static public key and always get the same shared key. If necessary, you could use *that* as input for HKDF.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it's an intriguing idea but not without drawbacks. If I did this, the output would be visible for at least as long as I needed it to subsequently convert it to an EC key. What I want is a chain of HKDF produced keys that cannot be extracted at any point. Perhaps I'm being needlessly paranoid about marking keys none exportable?!

Comment: No, I would never ever say that it is paranoid to keep things in a secure key store. That's their primary function after all. But note that you also need to make sure that the resulting value is between 0 and the order of the curve. And I wonder if it would not be easier to use a *secret key* as master key with a counter to use as source for HKDF / HMAC instead (sorry, missed the comment due to the stupid way SE handles comments, marking them all read at the same time).

Comment: Thanks Maarten. I'm going to have to go away and think about this and perhaps return with some code samples from other platforms where this work was possible.